How to reference another module in the folder parallel with the parent folder in Python?
Here is my project folder structure
|-- root
    |-- my_modules
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- main.py
        |-- m.py
    |--pipelines
        |--p.py

Basically there is nothing in the __init__ and main files of my_module folder, I just give a simple public method in the m.py file:
def foo():
   print('foo() in m.py')

I want to import the foo method in the p.py in the pipelines folder, and here is my code:
import sys

sys.path.append('..')
from my_modules import m

def p():
   m.foo()
   print('p')

p()

My question is, after I append the parent folder in the search path with sys.path.append, why it still cannot find my_mofules? How can I fix this problem?

'..' references the parent of the current working directory of the running Python process, not where the module is defined. You will need to use __file__ to resolve the actual parent dir relative to that module. Do note that this manipulation of sys.path is non-standard practice, packages is the standard way to ensure a collection of modules be used together.
